# How can I set an auto layout constraint in "viewForHeaderInSection" for a UILabel view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

```
 func tableView(tableView:UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> UIView?{
        let newlabel = UILabel()
        //206-250

        newlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (135/255), green:(206/255), blue: (250/255), alpha: 1)
        newlabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
        newlabel.textAlignment = .Right
        newlabel.font = newlabel.font.fontWithSize(18)
        newlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        let horizontalcontraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newlabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalcontraint])

        newlabel.constraints
        newlabel.text = keys[section]+" - "
        return newlabel
    }
```

I'm not sure how to reference the section header in the `toItem:` part of the constraint. Any advice would be appreciated. The UILabel is pinned up against the right side of the header and looks bad. I need a little spacing in there.

Comment: change value of -20 to 20 and try but i think it will not work because you are just using the label. According to me you should use a UIView and then add all king of constraint to the view from the label and return the UIView as header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have modified your code and here it is. Try once.

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> UIView?{
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let newlabel = UILabel()
    //206-250

    newlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (135/255), green:(206/255), blue: (250/255), alpha: 1)
    newlabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    newlabel.textAlignment = .Right
    newlabel.font = newlabel.font.fontWithSize(18)
    newlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    newlabel.constraints
    newlabel.text = keys[section]+" - "

    headerView.addSubview(newlabel)
    newlabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    headerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0))
    headerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    headerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: newlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` was the thing for me. So many hours must have been lost to this